# Ubuntu Customize

Tags: 18.04

I want the default color of Ubuntu that is **Orange** theme from everywhere and replace it with my personally choosen color.
For Example:

[image: Pop up for setting brightness, volume from top right corner]

And other places from where orange theme is displayed.
Thanks in advance and please suggest the correct solution..

Comment: manually editing each element color takes more time.. below answer is very easy to achieve what you want..

Answer (score 1):

You can install `gnome-tweaks` by

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

Then go to Ubuntu-software, search for "user themes" and install the extension.

You can now  download various themes from [gnome looks](https://www.gnome-look.org)

[image: Gnome-tweaks with appearance tab]

Comment: no that i have already applied a theme but in that, this colors are not changing and i want to customize this slider colors according to my personal choice.

Comment: You can try this theme https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013698/ download this and extract it move all the folders inside the main folder to .themes in home and from gnome looks change shell theme.

Comment: Or you can select a theme from https://www.gnome-look.org/search/projectSearchText/shell